# How to remove all punctuation marks from a sentence?

Tags: c++, cin

I'm new to C++ and is trying to solve the beginner's problem of trying to remove all punctuation marks from a sentence. Below is the code I have came up with. However, when I entered "Hello! Hello!", the compiler output "Hello" instead of "Hello Hello" (which is what I would expect).

Why is this happening?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(){

    cout << "please enter a sentence which include one or more punctuation marks" << endl;    
    string userInput;
    string result;
    cin >> userInput;
    decltype(userInput.size()) n;
    for (n = 0; n < userInput.size(); n++){
        if(!ispunct(userInput[n])){
            result += userInput[n];
            cout << result << endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Input:

```
Hello! Hello!
```

Compiler output:

```
Hello
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you do `cin >> userInput`, it only reads up to the first white-space character in the input stream.

You probably want to use `std::getline` instead (it'll read the entire line, by default).

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `getline()` function. Read about it [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/).

Welcome to C++! Read up about [stringstreams](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/stringstream/) they are very good at manipulating strings

Comment: Thank you so much for the advice!

Answer (score 1):

As others already said, you use `getline` to read a whole line of text.

I wanted to also point out there are functions in `<algorithm>` that make this kind of thing much cleaner.  Instead of looping over your string, you can use [`std::remove_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::string line;
    while( std::getline( std::cin, line ) )
    {
        line.erase( std::remove_if( line.begin(), line.end(), ispunct ), line.end() );
        std::cout << line << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thank you so much! so awesome to have people like  you guys to help beginners out!

Comment: Given that he's copying from `userInput` to `result`, `std::remove_copy_if` is probably a better fit.